# Using “NOT” to make a contrast

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

> - The criminals should be punished, **not** awarded medals.
> - The criminals shouldn’t be awarded medals, but punished.

Is there any grammatical mistake in these sentences

I am just being doubtful of using **not** to make a contrast in the same sentence.

Is using not to make a contrast acceptable in this sentence?

Comment: Both sentences look good to me, except I would omit the article: *Criminals should be punished, not rewarded.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sentences are correct.

The second phrase is parallel to the first, so "(should) not (be) awarded medals" is the understood meaning of the first. For the second, "but (should be) punished" is understood for the second. The contrast implied by "but" and the context makes the second sentence clear.